# How do I load a csv from my local machine (mac) to Spark-Neo4j docker?

Tags: neo4j, apache-spark, docker

I created a Spark-Neo4j VM using Docker in my Mac, and was able to successfully load the http://192.168.99.100:7474/browser. I am also able to run normal queries. 
I have a dataset.csv which I want to load to create the graph DB, but I am getting "Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/neo4j/community/code/data-3.csv". I can run that file at my local Neo4j server, but wanted to try with Spark.

What do I do to setup a path directly from my local machine, or is there a way I can transfer the dataset to docker?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`docker cp` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy the CSV file from the host to the container filesystem:

```
docker cp data-3.csv CONTAINER_ID_HERE:/data/data-3.csv
```

Then use the specified path in the `LOAD CSV` statement:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data/data-3.csv" ...
```

Another easy approach is to serve the CSV file from [Google spreadsheeet](http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/07/using-loadcsv-to-import-data-from.html) or Dropbox and use the URL in the `LOAD CSV` statement.

Comment: Hi William, thanks! I was able to get this done earlier today by using the same command. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found that I had to specify a particular destination folder for any import files in the Docker image. It looked like this: **docker cp SOURCE_FILE_LOCATION CONTAINER_ID_HERE:/var/lib/neo4j/import/DESTINATION_NAME.csv**